# Sum of independent Wishart with same degrees of freedom but different scale matrices

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, wishart-distribution

Is there any result showing that a sum of independent Wishart with same degrees of freedom but different scale matrices is a Wishart?

For example, if I have two random variables:
$$
Y \sim W_p(n,\sigma_1)\  \\
X \sim W_p(n, \sigma_2),
$$

where $p$ is the dimension of matrices, will $Y+X$ be equal to $W_p(n, \sigma_1 + \sigma_2)$?

Comment: When $p=1$, Wishart is Gamma, and the sum is not Gamma.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Even with the same shape parameters, sum of Gammas is not Gamma. Thank You, Stéphane. –